# Java Checkstyle severity level inherit meaning?

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

What actuallly does severity level set as "inherit" mean in a checkstyle rule?

tried googling a lot couldn't find an actual definition for this-

Comment: use same of parent ? thats what it should be

Comment: Parent? okay consider the following example a rule for abstract class name or constant variable name is defined with severity as inherit who would be the parent here?

Comment: Please post the log or the stylesheet with the necessary information. As far as I know inherited is not a valid value for checkstyle severity.

Comment: @Thihara : actually it shows in the drop down of eclipse-cs integrator, which i guess is the checkstyle plugin for eclipse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Checkstyle rules are configured in a small, but important hierarchy. `Checker` is at the top, one of its "children" is `Treewalker`, and so on. Properties can be defined for individual checks, but also for these "parent checks". Thus, your run-of-the-mill Checkstyle configuration file looks like this:

```xml
<module name="Checker">
    <property name="severity" value="warning"/>  <!-- NOTE THIS -->
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <property name="tabWidth" value="4"/>
        <module name="JavadocMethod">
            <property name="scope" value="public"/>
        </module>
    <!-- and so on -->
    </module>
    <!-- and so on -->
</module>
```

As you can see, there is the `severity` property of `Checker`, the topmost module. If a check somewhere lower in the hierarchy has its severity set to `inherit` (which is the same as not setting anything), then its severity will be, in this example, `warning`.

Answer (score 0):

> Command line properties and ant Checkstyle task properties apply to
>   the root Checker module. Also, properties are inherited in the module
>   hierarchy.

See [Checkstyle documentation](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html#Properties) for further details.

Comment: so does this mean that if I have a custom checkstyle configuration it would inherit from the default configuration i.e. sun checks?
So if I understand correctly the severity for such a rule defined would be same as the one defined in "Sun Checks"?

Comment: "...Also, properties are inherited in the module hierarchy." Inherited from where is my question actually?